# DrawerLayout; Icone not showing.. UP instead

Tags: android, navigation, drawerlayout, drawer

See for yourselves: 
[image: Samsung Galaxy S3]

**

### Samsung Galaxy S3

**

[image: Emulator with API19]

**

### Emulator with API 19 !

**

I don't understand why's that, oh and I tested it with a Motorola, I forgot the model exactly; it worked weel, but like I said; not on the S3, S4, Nexus 5...

Can you please explain?

Here's the code:

```
drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);
    menu = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Menu);
    listElements = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.listElements);

    //Relier le menu (listview) avec un adapter: (context, layout d'un element d'une liste, les elements a inserer)
    menu.setAdapter(new  ArrayAdapter <String>(this, R.layout.item_list1, listElements));


//------------------Instanciation du toggle (Utilisation d'une classe anonyme)----------------------------------------
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,
            R.string.open,
            R.string.close){

            //Après fermeture !<
        public void onDrawerClosed(View v){
            super.onDrawerClosed(v);
            getActionBar().setTitle(title);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
        //Après l'ouverture:
        public void onDrawerOpened(View v){
            super.onDrawerOpened(v);
            getActionBar().setTitle("Menu de l'application");
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };//----------------------------------------------------------------------

    //togge --> drawerListener; puisque la classe ActionBarDrawerToggle hérite de la classe DrawerListener

    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);       
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);  

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
     toggle.syncState();
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
            <include
        android:id="@+id/ContenuPrincipal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/activity_main_relative"
        /> 

    <!-- ListView... La liste des options du menu -->
       <ListView
            android:id="@+id/Menu"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#333"
            android:divider="#666"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            />  


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I think that the XML file for the Items is not really important here so..
Ok I think that I've putted everything important. I hope that my problem is clear. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same issue, and get it solved by adding the following just before initializing the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` object.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```